# How do I see if the contents of a csv file exists as a file in another directory?

Tags: python, scripting

EDIT:
To better explain my dilemma, I have a csv file that lists a number of applications numbered XXXXXX. Each of these applications have a corresponding xml file that exists in another directory. I'm essentially attempting to write a script that.

1. unzips the folder that contains the xml files and the csv file.
2. parse the entries within the csv file and sees that that each application listed in the csv file has a corresponding xml file.
3. Output another CSV file that sets an application to true if the xml file exists.

So far I've written the script to unzip, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around step 2 and 3.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import zipfile
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


def unzipXML(root):
    
    print(f'({datetime.now().strftime("%b. %d - %H:%M:%S")}) Stage 1 of 5: Unzipping folder(s)...')
    
    # Get filepaths of .zip files
    zipPaths = []
    for filename in os.listdir(root):
        if filename.endswith(".zip"):
            zipPaths.append(root + "/" + filename)

    # Unzip all .zip files
    for path in zipPaths:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'r') as zipRef:
            zipRef.extractall(root)

    print(f'({datetime.now().strftime("%b. %d - %H:%M:%S")}) {len(zipPaths)} folder(s) unzipped successfully.')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What are the columns in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the names in the `csv`, calling `os.path.exists()` on each one.

```
with open("filenames.csv") as inf, open("apps.csv", "w") as outf:
    in_csv = csv.reader(inf)
    out_csv = csv.writer(outf)
    for row in in_csv:
        app_name = row[0] # replace [0] with the correct field number for your CSV
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(directory_path, app_name + ".xml")):
            out_csv.writerow([app_name, 'exists'])
        else:
            out_csv.writerow([app_name, 'notexists'])
```

Comment: What if the file name and the xml don't have the exact naming convention? For example the xml file name is: CA-BFT-3155750-20220425.xml where as the entry in the csv file lists it as 3155750?

Comment: Also does this script work for the entry within the csv file or does it take the csv files name? I guess what i'm trying to do here is parse the file for application numbers and see if there is a corresponding xml file.

Comment: If there's a regular pattern, you can easily write code to extract it. E.g. `app_name = row[0].split('-')[2]`

Comment: Can't you read the code and see what it's doing? It's not very complicated. It clearly gets the entry from the CSV file: `for row in in_csv:`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem, but maybe this will help:

```
#Get files from path
List_Of_Files = glob.glob('./' + '\\*.csv')

for file_name in List_Of_Files:
    if file_name == your_var:
        ...
```